# bash wait max X minutes or when program exit run

Tags: bash, while-loop, wait

I run a script -> `scriptB` that monitor a process -> `scriptA`.
The idea is simple, if `scriptA` is running, wait, otherwise do some stuff, the problem is that I want to wait max 5 minutes but I've some problem, the `scriptB` run but use a lot of resources, and won't stop when `scriptA` is closed ...
From `scriptA` I run `scriptB` with `bash scriptB &`
then inside `scriptB` I've this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "creating lock file"
touch "B.lockfile"

script_A_istances=`ps --no-headers -C scriptA.sh | wc -l`

start_time=$(date +%s)
max_seconds=$(( 5 * 60 )) # minutes * seconds

while [[ $(($(date +%s) - $start_time)) -ne $max_seconds ]]; do
    if [ ${script_A_istances} -lt 1 ]; then
        echo "scriptB closed"
        rm -rf "B.lockfile"
        exit
    fi
done

echo "deleting lock file"
rm -rf "B.lockfile"
```

Like I said, `scriptB` start but cpu is used in a massive way, then if I stop `scriptA`, `scriptB` continue running and the lockfile is not deleted, I've to kill it and manually delete the lockfile

Seems so easy to do, but make me crazy, what do you think is the best approach to do this simple task?
Maybe the logic is awkward and can be better?
My thought is that the first while continue to run but I don't know how to stop it.

Any idea?

Jo

Comment: _Always_ have a delay inside your loop so it doesn't eat CPU endlessly; as soon as you finish running one check of the current time your script _immediately_ runs another without any delay, so *of course* it eats massive CPU! Just `sleep 1` will do some good. And if you have a new enough bash to have built-in date support, stop using `date +%s`; it's much more efficient to run `printf -v current_unix_time '%(%s)T' -1` than `current_unix_time=$(date +%s)`.

Comment: `if [ ${script_A_istances} -lt 1 ]; then` You are not changing the variable inside the loop, so.. it's not checking anything.

Comment: Beyond that, it's a bad idea to use `touch` and `rm` to manage lockfiles. You can have two processes that both think they hold the lock at the same time, because two `touch` operations that happen at the same time will both succeed. Use `flock` to grab locks, and don't ever delete the files they're on; keeping the files and reusing them makes sure that every program that tries to grab a lock is getting it on the same backing file, not two different files that happened to have the name at different times. (Remember, a file on UNIX can be deleted but still exist!)

Comment: ...and yes, what KamilCuk said; if you want to check the process tree, you need to actually run `ps` again to check the process tree again; when you store a command's output in a variable, you store the output it had *at the time it was first assigned*; that output doesn't get updated until you do something tho modify the variable. But *don't do that*; instead, use `flock` for your flocking. It's far more efficient than polling, so it's more than just a correctness fix.

Comment: Ok, so first, I moved the script_A_istances inside the 1st while, so the var is now updated. Now I'll try to make some searched about all your suggestion in order to better understand where I can improve the code. scriptB will never created if lockfile exist, but I'll try lo use flock.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `timeout` and `pgrep` (linux/bsd) you can simplify a lot:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "creating lock file"
touch "B.lockfile"

timeout --foreground 5m sh -c 'while pgrep scriptA.sh > /dev/null; do sleep 1; done'

echo "deleting lock file"
rm -rf "B.lockfile"
```

pgrep looks for scriptA in a loop in a shell, started by timeout. It exits if pgrep doesn't find scriptA running or if waiting for more than 5m.

[man pgrep](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pgrep.1.html)

[man timeout](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html)

Comment: I like the idea, I never thought about timeout in this way. My very first idea was to use timeout inside scriptA to launch scriptB but never used ...

Answer (score 0):

After your advice, I modified the script

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "creating lock file"
touch "B.lockfile"

start_time=$(date +%s)
max_seconds=$(( 1 * 60 )) # minutes * seconds

while [[ $(($(date +%s) - $start_time)) -ne $max_seconds ]]; do
    script_A_istances=`ps --no-headers -C scriptA.sh | wc -l`
    if [ ${script_A_istances} -lt 1 ]; then
        echo "scriptB closed"
        rm -rf "B.lockfile"
        exit
    fi
    sleep 1
done

echo "deleting lock file"
rm -rf "B.lockfile"
```

I moved the `script_A_istances` inside the loop, quite noob error, and added the `sleep 1` timer, now is not so greedy! I searched about `flock`, right now I don't know if I can use it, I've to find extra information, right now the lockfile is created and deleted only from `scriptB`, `scriptA` won't create `scriptB` if the lockfile is present.